# Alterar classe de objeto <i> dentro da tag <a>

Tags: html, jquery, css

Com o seguinte código:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary botao" style="background-color:#009999" onclick="importar_txt_cnes()"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size:1em;"></i> Importar</a>
```

Testei assim, mas não funcionou:

```
function importar_txt_cnes(){
    $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-bolt').addClass('fa-spinner');
}
```

Como fazer pra trocar a classe `fa fa-bolt` para `fa fa-spinner` quando o usuário clicar no link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta acessar o elemento **filho** do alvo do evento usando o método [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) e usar os métodos [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) e [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) para trocar as classes:

```js
$('.botao').on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-bolt').addClass('fa-spinner');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class="btn btn-primary botao">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i> Importar
</a>
```

PS: Não sei se você percebeu, mas adicionei a classe [`fa-fw`](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#fixed-width) ao HTML. Isso é para fazer com que ambos os ícones tenham o mesmo tamanho, evitando uma transição desagradável aos olhos do usuário. ;)

**Edit:**

Se você, por alguma razão, precisar definir o *listener* de evento no HTML, você pode fazer assim:

```js
function importar_txt_cnes(){
  $('.botao > i').removeClass('fa-bolt').addClass('fa-spinner');
}
```

Note, no entanto, que definir os eventos diretamente no HTML **não é uma boa prática**. Sempre prefira defini-los diretamente no código JavaScript, conforme exemplificado no primeiro trecho de código dessa resposta.

Comment: oi amigo, preciso que seja chamada a função `onclick="importar_txt_cnes()"` pois nela irei enviar parametros em cada botao

Comment: testei seu código dentro da funcao que criei e nao funciona. preciso modificar algo?

Comment: alterei a pergunta mostrando como estou usando o codigo que voce me passou

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando mais detalhes...

Answer (score 1):

Envie o `this` como parâmetro para a função no `onclick`. O `this` representa o elemento que chamou a função, ou seja, caso você tenha mais de um botão, será alterado o ícone do botão clicado.

Pode apenas trocar o nome "bolt" por "spinner" com replace:

```js
function importar_txt_cnes(e){
   e.firstChild.className = e.firstChild.className.replace('bolt' ,'spinner');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="btn btn-primary botao" style="background-color:#009999" onclick="importar_txt_cnes(this)"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size:1em;"></i> Importar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary botao" style="background-color:#009999" onclick="importar_txt_cnes(this)"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size:1em;"></i> Importar</a>
```

Com jQuery pode usar o método `.toggleClass()` adicionando a nova classe sem remover a outra, porque o prevalece é a última classe do atributo `class`:

```js
function importar_txt_cnes(e){
   $('i', e).toggleClass('fa-spinner', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a class="btn btn-primary botao" style="background-color:#009999" onclick="importar_txt_cnes(this)"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size:1em;"></i> Importar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary botao" style="background-color:#009999" onclick="importar_txt_cnes(this)"><i class="fa fa-bolt" style="font-size:1em;"></i> Importar</a>
```